# Вставка JS кода в latex

Tags: latex

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне вставить JS код в Latex

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для того чтобы он выглядел после преобразования из tex в pdf код выглядел в своем первоначальном виде , а не так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте пакет [listings](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/):

```latex
\usepackage{listings}
```

Пример использования:

```latex
\begin{lstlisting}
class Node {
    constructor(value, next) {
        this.value = value
        this.next = next
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: Предложу альтернативу - пакет minted: https://ctan.altspu.ru/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf Его использовать несколько сложнее (нужен Python в ОС и разрешить редактору обращаться к консоли), но он понимает многие языки и подсвечивает синтаксис. Особенно удобно, если кода не 3 строки, а отдельный файл, который можно подключить.